# Need Inputs on the XSD Schema

Tags: xsd, tibco

I am looking for suggestions to create the XSD structure to handle the following XML format so that my processing logic will be more efficient.The looping logic will be managed in TIBCO BW

```
<Line>
    <ShipmentLineNumber>1</ShipmentLineNumber>
    <SalesOrderLineNumber>1.1</SalesOrderLineNumber>
    <PurchaseOrderLineNumber>1</PurchaseOrderLineNumber>
    <PartNumber>1CH162-510</PartNumber>
    <ModelNumber>ST1000DM003</ModelNumber>
</Line>
<Package packageType="P" packageLevel="1">
    <PackageNumber>PWN34332</PackageNumber>
    <ShipmentNumber>105909390</ShipmentNumber>
    <ShipmentLineNumber>1</ShipmentLineNumber>
    <PartNumber>1CH162-510</PartNumber>
    <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
    <SSCCNumber>00176364909402100165</SSCCNumber>
</Package>
<Package packageType="C" packageLevel="2">
    <PackageNumber>CWX612432660</PackageNumber>
    <ParentPackageNumber>PWN34332</ParentPackageNumber>
    <ShipmentNumber>105909390</ShipmentNumber>
    <ShipmentLineNumber>1</ShipmentLineNumber>
    <PartNumber>1CH162-510</PartNumber>
    <Quantity>25</Quantity>
    <SSCCNumber>00176364909402100165</SSCCNumber>
</Package>
<Package packageType="S" packageLevel="3">
    <PackageNumber>W1D2WNGL</PackageNumber>
    <ParentPackageNumber>CWX612432660</ParentPackageNumber>
    <ShipmentNumber>105909390</ShipmentNumber>
    <ShipmentLineNumber>1</ShipmentLineNumber>
    <PartNumber>1CH162-510</PartNumber>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <DateOfMfg>20131209</DateOfMfg>
    <COO>CN</COO>
    <SSCCNumber>00176364909402100165</SSCCNumber>
    <SerialAttribute1>CN0G1XNT212323C60C25</SerialAttribute1>
    <SerialAttribute3>A02</SerialAttribute3>
    <SerialAttribute5>CC47</SerialAttribute5>
    <SerialAttribute6>B719</SerialAttribute6>
    <SerialAttribute7>GPG17B.CCD4.DC0CAL.CC47</SerialAttribute7>
</Package>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *so that my processing logic will be more efficient*.

Comment: My processing logic to pick the package level3, Package level2 and Package level1 items

Comment: The XSD structure has to match the XML structure.  So it is rather unclear what you are asking.   Do you control the XML structure or is that given to you?

Comment: XML is given to us. we need to create the schema so that we can loop thru the nodes to extract the information

Answer (score 0):

You can use online tools [like this](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) to help you reasonably **guess** the XSD structure matching this XML instance, but that will probably not suffice unless you have an instance presenting all possible combinations and values of each element.

Besides, your current XML instance is invalid because it is missing a root element.